# SSL Exception when WebService endpoint url has https

Tags: web-services, ssl, jax-ws

I am getting the below exception when I invoke a jax ws webservice from my application deployed in WebSphere Application Server 6.1

SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE:  A signer with SubjectDN "CN=yyy.com, OU=For Intranet Use Only, OU=Web Hosting, O=xx, L=xx, ST=xx, C=xx" was sent from target host:port "*:9445".  The signer may need to be added to local trust store "F://../trust.p12" .  The extended error message from the SSL handshake exception is: "No trusted certificate found".

The enpoint url has https.
With the same enpoint url I am able to get a response from SOAP UI(Tool) without any certificate configuration etc..

Could you help me on this ?

Comment: Can you append the relative section from the WAS SystemOut.log? Since you are programatically creating the SSL connection (You are not a browser) then the WAS SSL Chain will need to be able to establish a chain of trust for the incoming server SSL cert. This is normal. I don't know why SOAP UI works here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to fix this small issue.The Server certificate needs to be added to the websphere appserver truststore.This can be done from the admin console of websphere by providing the server domain and port.